# What does "over" in "overpass-the-hash" mean?

Tags: hash, kerberos, ntlm

I have to translate this sentence: 'Suspected overpass-the-hash attack (Kerberos)' and I found this article about overpass-the-hash: https://blog.stealthbits.com/how-to-detect-overpass-the-hash-attacks/ There I found this sentence: 'Not only did we just pass-the-hash, we overpassed it!'. So I understand 'pass the hash' as to 'transfer the hash', right? But what does 'over' add? Excessive amount, a jump to another place?

Comment: I don't know, but https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJQn06QLwEw seems to be the source of the term. My guess is it's a jump to another place: The stolen hash is not just passed on to log into other things, but is used to create a fresh Kerberos ticket.

Answer (score 8):

The "over" in overpass-the-hash refers to taking the pass-the-hash technique one step further to acquire a valid Kerberos ticket.

Typically, with pass-the-hash you use a NT hash from a compromised user account for use to directly authenticate to remote services as that user, either by injecting into the memory of the current Windows user or providing the hash directly to client applications which accept it (e.g. CrackMapExec).

With overpass-the-hash you can leverage that NT hash twice over to now request a full Kerberos TGT or service ticket from the KDC on behalf of that compromised user. This technique also opens up the **pass-the-ticket** attack vector, where now that forged but valid (before expiration) TGT/ST can be exported and re-injected for future use and bypass communication with the KDC. Because they are closely linked, overpass-the-hash and pass-the-ticket are often used interchangeably.

I agree that many of the top search result blog posts do not clearly explain the unique mechanism of OPTH. For a more direct explanation, check out the "[Abusing Kerberos](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-14/materials/us-14-Duckwall-Abusing-Microsoft-Kerberos-Sorry-You-Guys-Don't-Get-It-wp.pdf)" whitepaper by the Mimikatz developers. Also checkout [detection exercise](https://blog.stealthbits.com/how-to-detect-pass-the-hash-attacks/) linked in the blog you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Pass-the-hash relies on interacting directly with the DC in order to generate a TGT or TGS ticket, as one example.  Pass-the-hash is equivalent to going through the authentication process with the DC, but using the hash directly.  The result of this process is LSASS process memory now contains a DC-certified TGT or TGS, generated by the DC.

Overpass-the-hash is a direct write operation of a forged TGT or TGS directly into LSASS process memory for the currently logged-in user, bypassing authenticating or interacting directly with the DC.  The key here is that the end result is a TGT or TGS written to LSASS process memory of the currently logged-in user, without ever having had any direct interaction with the DC.   And since that TGT is signed by the "krbtgt" user account hash, or the TGS is signed by the machine_account or service_account hash of the target service, it is considered valid by the DC when it goes to validate the TGT or TGS.  This is because those are the only sensitive pieces of information needed to validate either one.

This is talked about at least to partial extent at the following article titled "*NIX Kerberos + MS Active Directory fun and games", http://passing-the-hash.blogspot.com/2016/06/nix-kerberos-ms-active-directory-fun.html.   Other bits come from direct experience.

Now, I can't tell you why the specific verbiage chosen was "over", but I can tell you that this is what the difference between the two methods is.  I suspect "over" comes from going over the head of the DC in order to obtain the TGT or TGS?  Have fun!

Comment: This answer describes the Kerberos golden ticket attack which uses forged tickets, not overpass-the-hash which extends the pass-the-hash attack to request a Kerberos TGT from the Kerberos KDC (the Domain Controller).

Answer (score 0):

**Think of the "OVER" in *Overpass-the-hash* as a motorway overpass that drives over the KDC's Auth Server and goes straight to the Ticket Granting Service.**

Instead of firstly giving the hash to the Auth Server, you "overpass" the **AS** and give it to the **TGS**.

[This image from intel is a good illustration](https://software.intel.com/sites/manageability/AMT_Implementation_and_Reference_Guide/ImagesExt/image861_0.png) of the auth flow.

I hope this helps. I too did not find the name "Overpass-the-hash" intuative.